# Is there an easy way to display (received) incoming multipart mail (email)?

Tags: java, email, frameworks

**I'm developing a Java web app in which in some cases i have to display the content of an incoming mail.** It can be any type of mail (plain, multipart).

As you can guess i had no problem with text/plain or with text/html. I even managed to display the text part of a multipart email. But...

The problem comes when i'd like to display inline images and/or handling attachments (make them downloadable).

**Basically i'm looking for a framework that would help my work by parsing the mail to a format (?) which is easier to handle or even display.**

Please note currently i'm not looking for help on the java mail API in general. I simply don't wish to implement this on my own.

Thanks in advance!
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my solution in the following post:
[Java Mail - read in the attachment as String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054093/java-mail-read-in-the-attachment-as-string/12057124#12057124)

(community wiki answer)