# Java Mail - read in the attachment as String

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am beginning to work with Java Mail and I have a few questions about processing of attachment:

1. If our content is a `Multipart` i.e. has an attachment, at which index is the actual attachment and at which can we find the message content? I simply want to process just attachments.
2. Would it be a correct approach. if I wanted to convert a given attachment to a String, to simply read through the stream of the attachment part (using `getStream()`) and append it to String builder and then return a String?

Thanks a lot for any advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) 
This is from one of my applications (also based on someone else's code but i could not find to give credit).

As you can see i'm recursively processing a Part object (first it's actually a Message).

I removed some code which is irrelevant.

```
private BodyPartDOM collectBodyParts(Part part) throws IOException, MessagingException {

        BodyPartDOM dom = new BodyPartDOM();

        Object content = part.getContent();

        if (content instanceof String) {

            // process as string

        } else if (content instanceof Multipart) {


            Multipart innerMultiPart = (Multipart) content;
            int count = innerMultiPart.getCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                BodyPart innerBodyPart = innerMultiPart.getBodyPart(i);
                BodyPartDOM subDom = collectBodyParts(innerBodyPart);
                // further recursive processing

            }

        } else if (content instanceof InputStream) {

            // process inputStream

        }

        return dom;

    }
```

2.) If you convert it to a String go ahead. But watch out for file streams for example.

You can check the mime type for the content type. Here are some infor from wikipedia that will help (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Type):

> Content-Type This header indicates the Internet media type of the
>   message content, consisting of a type and subtype, for example
>
> Content-Type: text/plain Through the use of the multipart type, MIME
>   allows messages to have parts arranged in a tree structure where the
>   leaf nodes are any non-multipart content type and the non-leaf nodes
>   are any of a variety of multipart types. This mechanism supports:
>
> simple text messages using text/plain (the default value for
>   "Content-Type: ") text plus attachments (multipart/mixed with a
>   text/plain part and other non-text parts). A MIME message including an
>   attached file generally indicates the file's original name with the
>   "Content-disposition:" header, so the type of file is indicated both
>   by the MIME content-type and the (usually OS-specific) filename
>   extension reply with original attached (multipart/mixed with a
>   text/plain part and the original message as a message/rfc822 part)
>   alternative content, such as a message sent in both plain text and
>   another format such as HTML (multipart/alternative with the same
>   content in text/plain and text/html forms) image, audio, video and
>   application (for example, image/jpeg, audio/mp3, video/mp4, and
>   application/msword and so on) many other message constructs

How to put that into practice can be found here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html

Happy coding!

Comment: OK, but how you distinguish between an attachement, which might be a csv file for instance?

Comment: @dbalakirev Can you add some code example for the process inputStream part?